# MediaWiki 1.16.4: Script to upload multiple image files

Tags: php, python, mediawiki

I am using MediaWiki 1.16.4 and currently have to migrate from a help site using HTML to a new help site with mediawiki. One problem I bump into is to upload a mass amount of images onto mediawiki without using the web interface (since that would take forever and a half). I am currently trying to use pywikipedia (which is a python bot) for the task but haven't succeeded yet. Does any of you happen to know a script for the task?

Thansk,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I have found the answer. It turns out that MW 1.16.4 provides its own script for bulk media upload which can be found here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php

Answer (score 1):

See the section "Blatant hack" here: http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki_Bulk_Page_Creator for a PHP script that does just that.

As with many of those bot scripts, you'll need the PHP Snoopy library available. This script is pretty old and doesn't use the API, so I'm not sure if it will work with the new CSRF protection. If a newer one exists, I haven't found it.

It might be a good idea to rewrite it to use the API, it's not that hard. If you want to do that I have a demo of how to use PHP with cURL to login with the API here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Bcoughlan/Login_with_curl

Comment: I am using 1.16.4 so all the URL are different now ... I don't know if that is going to work though. I will give it a try :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try [upload.py](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Pywikipediabot/upload.py) from the [pywikipedia bot framework](http://pywikipediabot.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I am trying it now. But it's throwing this error at me: `Logging in to nishtest:en as tahoang via API.
Error downloading data: No JSON object could be decoded
Request en:/nishtest/api.php?`

Answer (score 0):

I got so irritated with how the existing tools have massive amounts of code for this simple thing. So I built my own.  Including a mass image file uploader (and downloader) in python.

You may need to do a little python hacking because it may not be polished; but it shows how it can be done in just a few lines of code.

The code is here:
https://github.com/gandrewstone/mediawiki_python_bot